# PowerShell script that searches for a string in a .txt and if it finds it, looks for the next line containing another string and does a job with it

Tags: powershell, text

I have the line

`Select-String -Path ".\*.txt" -Pattern "6,16" -Context 20 | Select-Object -First 1`

that would return 20 lines of context looking for a pattern of "6,16".

I need to look for the next line containing the string "ID number:" after the line of "6,16", read what is the text right next to "ID number:", find if this exact text exists in another "export.txt" file located in the same folder (so in ".\export.txt"), and see if it contains "6,16" on the same line as the one containing the text in question.

I know it may seem confusing, but what I mean is for example:

`example.txt:5218: ID number:0002743284`

shows whether this is true:

`export.txt:9783: 0002743284 *some text on the same line for example* 6,16`

Comment: In the post you say you need to find the same text "on the same line", but in the sample text it's clearly two different lines (line 5218 versus line 9783) - which is it?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: There are _two_ files involved, and the line numbers relate to different files. The question could be fleshed out a bit more, but the gist is: "Find a pattern in one file, extract a substring from the 20 lines following the match, then find the extracted substring in a second file, followed by the original pattern on the same line."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking for something like:

```sh
Select-String -List -Path *.txt -Pattern '\b6,16\b' -Context 0, 20 |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Context.PostContext -join "`n" -match '\bID number:(\d+)') {
      Select-String -List -LiteralPath export.txt -Pattern "$($Matches[1]).+$($_.Pattern)"
    }
  }
```

- [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-List` switch limits the matching to *one* match per input file; `-Context 0,20` also includes the `20` lines *following* the matching one in the output (but none (`0`) *before*).

  - Note that I've placed `\b`, a [word-boundary assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#anchors) at either end of the search pattern, `6,16`, to rule out accidental false positives such as `96,169`.
- `$_.Context.PostContext` contains the array of lines following the matching line (which itself is stored in `$_.Line`):

  - `` -join "`n" `` joins them into a multi-line string, so as to ensure that the subsequent [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) operation reports the captured results in the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches), notably reporting the ID number of interest in `$Matches[1]`, the text captured by the first (and only) *capture group* (`(\d+)`).
- The captured ID is then used in combination with the original search pattern to form a regex that looks for both on the same line, and is passed to a second `Select-String` call that searches through `export.txt`

  - Note: An object representing the matching line, if any, is output by default; to return just `$true` or `$false`, replace `-List` with `-Quiet`.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Sv3n; my pleasure. As for your question: use `\b6,16\b` - please see my update for details.

Comment: @Sv3n, `Select-String` uses the same regex matching as the `-match` operator, and  both `'96,16' -match '\b6,16\b'` and `'16,16' -match '\b6,16\b'` return`$false`, whereas `' 6,16' -match '\b6,16\b'` returns `$true`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot wrong with what you're expecting and the code you've tried so let's break it down and get to the solution. Kudos for attempting this on your own. First, here's the solution, read below this code for an explanation of what you were doing wrong and how to arrive at the code I've written:

```
# Get matching lines plus the following line from the example.txt seed file
$seedMatches = Select-String -Path .\example.txt -Pattern "6,\s*16" -Context 0, 2

# Obtain the ID number from the line following each match
$idNumbers = foreach( $match in $seedMatches ) {
  $postMatchFields = $match.Context.PostContext -split ":\s*"

  # Note: .IndexOf(object) is case-sensitive when looking for strings
  # Returns -1 if not found
  $idFieldIndex = $postMatchFields.IndexOf("ID number")

  # Return the "ID number" to `$idNumbers` if "ID number" is found in $postMatchFields
  if( $idFieldIndex -gt -1 ) {
    $postMatchFields[$idFieldIndex + 1]
  }
}

# Match lines in export.txt where both the $id and "6,16" appear
$exportMatches = foreach( $id in $idNumbers ) {
  Select-String -Path .\export.txt -Pattern "^(?=.*\b$id\b)(?=.*\b6,\s*16\b).*$"
}
```

[mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68714703/powershell-script-that-searches-for-a-string-in-a-txt-and-if-it-finds-it-looks/68716243#68716243) essentially condenses this into less code, but I wanted to break this down fully.

---

First, `Select-String -Path ".\*.txt"` will look in all `.txt` files in the current directory. You'll want to narrow that down to a specific naming pattern you're looking for in the seed file (the file we want to find the ID to look for in the other files). For this example, I'll use `example.txt` and `export.txt` for the paths which you've used elsewhere in your question, without using globbing to match on filenames.

Next, `-Context` gives context of the surrounding lines from the match. You only care about the next line match so `0, 1` should suffice for `-Context` (0 lines before, 1 line after the match).

Finally, I've added `\s*` to the `-Pattern` to match on whitespace, should the `16` ever be padded from the `,`. So now we have our `Select-String` command ready to go:

```
$seedMatches = Select-String -Path .\example.txt -Pattern "6,\s*16" -Context 0, 2
```

---

Next, we will need to loop over the matching results from the seed file. You can use [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1) or [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1), but I'll use `foreach` in the example below.

For each `$match` in `$seedMatches` we'll need to get the `$idNumbers` from the lines following each match. When `$match` is `ToString()'d`, it will spit out the matched line and any surrounding context lines. Since we only have one line following the match for our context, we can grab `$match.Context.PostContext` for this.

Now we can get the `$idNumber`. We can split `example.txt:5218: ID number:0002743284` into an array of strings by using the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-5.1) operator to split the string on the `:\s*` pattern (`\s*` matches on any or no whitespace). Once we have this, we can get the index of "ID Number" and get the value of the field immediately following it. Now we have our `$idNumbers`. I'll also add some protection below to ensure the `ID numbers` field  is actually found before continuing.

```
$idNumbers = foreach( $match in $seedMatches ) {
  $postMatchFields = $match.Context.PostContext -split ":\s*"

  # Note: .IndexOf(object) is case-sensitive when looking for strings
  # Returns -1 if not found
  $idFieldIndex = $postMatchFields.IndexOf("ID number")

  # Return the "ID number" to `$idNumbers` if "ID number" is found in $postMatchFields
  if( $idFieldIndex -gt -1 ) {
    $postMatchFields[$idFieldIndex + 1]
  }
}
```

---

Now that we have `$idNumbers`, we can look in `export.txt` for this ID number "6,\s*16" on the same line, once again using `Select-String`. This time, I'll put the code first since it's nothing new, then explain the regex a bit:

```
$exportMatches = foreach( $id in $idNumbers ) {
  Select-String -Path .\export.txt -Pattern "^(?=.*\b$id\b)(?=.*\b6,\s*16\b).*$"
}
```

`$exportMatches` will now contain the lines which contain both the target `ID number` and the `6,16` value on the same line. Note that order wasn't specified so the expression uses [positive lookaheads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zero-width-positive-lookahead-assertions) to find both the `$id` and `6,16` values regardless of their order in the string. I won't break down the exact expression but if you plug `^(?=.*\b0123456789\b)(?=.*\b6,\s*16\b).*$` into https://regexr.com it will break down and explain the regex pattern in detail.

---

The full code is above in [at the top of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68716913/584676).